# Why use the -p|-n in slurp mode in perl one liner?

Tags: perl

In perl one liner slurp mode is `0777` I hope which is equal to below script

```
open my $fh, "<","file";
local $/;
my $s = <$fh>; #now whole file stored into the $s
```

Here we are not using any loop for storing all the elements together(single data).

But in perl one liner, Why do we use the `-p|-n` switch to enable the slurp mode (`-0777`)? What is the performance gain here.?

`-p | -n` using for looping purpose. So the actual performance of one liner is like the below script or anything else?

```
open my $fh, "<","file";
my $s;
while (<$fh>)
{ 
   $s.=$_;
}
print $s;
```

Comment: The `-p` and `-n` options affect whether Perl automatically loops and prints.  That is tangential to whether it loops once because of slurp mode or many times because it is not in slurp mode.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but with either of them the implicit `while (<>)` results in the `$_` actually being set, while without them it isn't.  So if we want to use `$_` in the slurp mode we need `-n` or `-p`. (I posted below with more.)

Comment: @zdim: without the `-p` or `-n` option, there is no implicit loop, nor any automatic reading of command line file names or standard input.  You'd have to add that yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that is what I mean -- I think that OP is asking that, why do we use them with slurp. It is so to have that loop so that `$_` does get set and we can use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without `-n` or `-p` there is no implicit `while (<>)` loop so the default `$_` does not get set, and the STDIN isn't read either. If we want to have `<>` and `$_` by default in the slurp mode we need one of these switches along with `-0777`, which on its own merely (un)sets `$/`. This

```
echo "hello" | perl -0777 -e 'print'
```

prints nothing, and with `-w` it warns of `Use of uninitialized value $_`. Now this

```
echo "hello" | perl -0777 -e '$v = <>; print $v'
```

does print `hello`. The `STDIN` can be read into a variable, so 'slurp' *is* on.

In terms of what this is equivalent to, mere `-0777` only does `$/ = undef`. If we add a read

```
# use warnings;
local $/;
<>; 
print;
```

The `<>` does read everything in one go but there is no *default input and pattern-searching space* ([variable `$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_))
so what is read is not assigned to anything. With the warnings on we get to hear about it. (Thanks to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for mentioning STDIN in a comment.)

The code equivalent to using `-n` is

```
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) { }
```

so we get standard input and `$_` set up.  Run `perl -MO=Deparse -n -e 1` to see these.

In [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) the conditions are listed for when "*... Perl will assume `$_` ...*".  The last bullet

> The default place to put the next value or input record when a `<FH>`, `readline`, `readdir` or `each` operation's result is tested by itself as the sole criterion of a `while` test. Outside a `while` test, this will not happen.

With `-n` or `-p` switches we get this, and all of standard input.

Note, your example is not exactly equivalent since it *does* assign.

---

Comment on specific statements in the question.

The slurp does not get "*enabled*" by these switches -- it is set up by the `-0777` flag.  We use them because we get automatic standard input and `$_` with them.

Answer (score 2):

It's more like running `perl -n0e '$s = $_'`:

```
% perl -MO=Deparse -n0e '$s = $_'
BEGIN { $/ = "\000"; $\ = undef; }                                                                                                                                                                                                
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    $s = $_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-e syntax OK
```

as you can see the only "overhead" is the one time check in the while. After all `$/` is a NUL byte. And as pointed out by others it's a simple way to get things done:

Consider this simple sed equal:

```
perl -i -pe 's/a/b/g' file1 file2 file3
```

The above will replace all `a`'s with `b`'s in file1, file2 & file3. Deparsed:

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    s/a/b/g;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
continue {                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons; firstly, to get the job done **in one line.**  The whole idea of one-liner is to avoid having to actually write a script file.  Your slurpy alternatives can't reasonably be expressed in a line.

Secondly, -n and -p allow action to be taken with each line - this is not the same thing as simply reading in all lines.  Having read in lines using your slurpy alternatives, one could then use map to process each line - but then we back to multiple lines of code instead of a command line switch.